# SQLiteException (0x8): attempt to write a readonly database

Tags: asp.net, sqlite

My web application uses SQLite as database. Application works in dev environment.

At the time of hosting, I have copied the database to a folder in the server and give full access (Read & Write) on file.

While inserting new data, getting error :

> attempt to write a readonly database

It was working fine before hosting.

Comment: While you have copied database have you close all sql connection and detach that database?

Comment: @Dwhitz : I do not know which explanation do you need. Its question seems clear. Its sqlite database cannot be updated after hosting.